# how to remove a style from a previously selected row in a gwt grid

Tags: gwt, datagrid, onclick, gwtquery

I want to remove a style from a previously selected row of a gwt DataGrid when clicked on a new row.
Im able to do it by redrawing the grid, is it possible to do it without redrawing the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/), just capture the event and use gquery to select the element in the dom you want to modify using css3 selectors.

If you put some code with the place where you want to capture the action, and the dom structure of your grid, I could help with the snippet.

Comment: Manolo, is gwtquery a part of gwt jars or do I have to add it as a plugin ?

Comment: gwtquery is a library that you have to import. It's lightweight and very convenient to include it in any GWT project. Despite the fact that it offers the same api than jquery, it's not a wrapper but an entire rewrite in java, so only stuff you use will go to your js.